# Drools Workbench not configuration in Wildfly 10

Tags: drools, wildfly-10, kie-workbench, drools-kie-server, drools-kie-workbench

I am using drools workbench 6.5.0 and trying to configure into Wildfly 10. I am gettings below error.

> Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
> {"jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-wildfly10.war".WeldStartService"
> => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-wildfly10.war".WeldStartService:
> Failed to start service Caused by:
> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1
> exceptions: Exception 0 : org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException:
> WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void
> org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.AppSetup.assertPlayground() on
> org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.AppSetup@26107fd0 at
> org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:100)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:81)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:126)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:171) at
> org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96) at
> org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:141)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
> at
> org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.AppSetup$Proxy$_$$*WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:162)
> at
> org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:143)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
> org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:309)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:124)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:287)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:450)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
> at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:96)
> at
> org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
> at
> org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
> org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:98)
> ... 37 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.NoSuchElementException at
> org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.AppSetup.assertPlayground(AppSetup.java:195)
> ... 42 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.util.NoSuchElementException at
> org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryServiceImpl.createRepository(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:283)
> at
> org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryServiceImpl$Proxy$*$$*WeldClientProxy.createRepository(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.AppSetup.createRepository(AppSetup.java:330)
> at
> org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.AppSetup.assertPlayground(AppSetup.java:119)
> ... 42 more Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException at
> java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:862) at
> org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystem$1$1.next(JGitFileSystem.java:194)
> at
> org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystem$1$1.next(JGitFileSystem.java:173)
> at
> org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.git.GitRepositoryBuilder.getDefaultRoot(GitRepositoryBuilder.java:120)
> at
> org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.git.GitRepositoryBuilder.setBranches(GitRepositoryBuilder.java:98)
> at
> org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.git.GitRepositoryBuilder.build(GitRepositoryBuilder.java:63)
> at
> org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.git.GitRepositoryFactoryHelper.newRepository(GitRepositoryFactoryHelper.java:64)
> at
> org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.git.GitRepositoryFactoryHelper$Proxy$*$$*WeldClientProxy.newRepository(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryFactoryImpl.newRepository(RepositoryFactoryImpl.java:61)
> at
> org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryFactoryImpl$Proxy$*$$_WeldClientProxy.newRepository(Unknown
> Source) at
> org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryServiceImpl.createRepository(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:96)
> at
> org.guvnor.structure.backend.repositories.RepositoryServiceImpl.createRepository(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:279)
> ... 45 more "}}

Machine : windows 10
Wildlfly Server : 10.0
Kie server 6.5.0 - working fine

Only problem is Drools work bench

Answer (score 1):

Drools Workbench 6.5.0 is targeted Wildfly 8, see [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#wb.warInstallation).

If you have to use Wildfly 10, please consider [Drools Workbench 7.0.0](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_wb.warinstallation)